# Problems in jQuery when hovering an image over the image?

Tags: jquery, image, hover

I have a page listing the images. And when I hover on that image it will display the play icon over the image.

I have written some jQuery code for that:

```
$('#hovervideo').mouseenter(function (){
    var isviddiv = $(this).find('.video-thumb');
    if(isviddiv.length){
        isviddiv.css('display','block');
    }
        console.log(isviddiv.length);
});
$('#hovervideo').mouseleave(function (){
    var isviddiv = $(this).find('.video-thumb');
    if(isviddiv.length){
        isviddiv.css('display','none');
    }
        console.log(isviddiv.length);
});
```

Html Part

```
<h1 class="productvideo" id="hovervideo"><a href="#"><img src="images/tst-img.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                <span class="video-thumb"></span>
                </h1>
```

but it will work only for one image. bcoz the id "hovervideo" is same for all the H1. but i want it in all the image hover effect.

Can any one suggest me what to do.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the class selector instead, add the class "test-image" to all images as so:

```
<h1 class="productvideo" id="hovervideo"><a href="#"><img src="images/tst-img.jpg" class="test-image" alt="" /></a>
                <span class="video-thumb"></span>
                </h1>
```

Then change the script to use the class selector

```
$('.test-image').mouseenter(function (){
    var isviddiv = $(this).find('.video-thumb');
    if(isviddiv.length){
        isviddiv.css('display','block');
    }
        console.log(isviddiv.length);
});
$('.test-image').mouseleave(function (){
    var isviddiv = $(this).find('.video-thumb');
    if(isviddiv.length){
        isviddiv.css('display','none');
    }
        console.log(isviddiv.length);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have more than one element with the same ID. Id should be a *unique* identifier.
If you want the event to be bound to multiple elements, simply select them by class:

```
$('.productvideo')...
```